# changing layout of a gxp.plugins.WMSGetFeatureInfo response

Tags: boundless-suite

Have a little problem with an app I’m building.
I´m using the openGeo suite SDK to create an app. I added a WMSGetFeatureInfo tool following the Boundless tutorial and to that point it was all ok. Then I decided to change the Templates to get just the meaningful part of the data. I made a Template following instructions [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html).
If I preview the layers using OpenLayers and click any feature I get the right answer but then if I go to my app and use the WMSGetFeatureInfo tool it ignores the config and shows me all the fields in the layer.

What I’m I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure format is set to 'html' on the WMSGetFeatureInfo plugin and not 'grid'.

Comment: THX I knew I was missing something...